# Circular array based queue

Tags: queue

May I know is there a way to dequeue an item from a certain index in a circular array?

Example 
Imagine this is a circular array...

> > 1---2--3---4-5---6--7-8
> >     |11|76|45|32|32|16|21|8|
>
> dequeue index 3
>
> > 1---2--3---4-5---6--7-8
> >     |11|76|45|32|32|16|21|8|
> >
> > 1---2--3---4-5---6--7-8
> >     |11|76|EM|32|32|16|21|8|
>
> EM stands for empty.
>
> dequeue index 8
>
> > 1---2--3---4-5---6---7--8
> >     |11|76|EM|32|32|16|21|EM|

Is there a way? Or do I need to shift all of them together then it will work? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages, when you'd like to remove an element, you have to shift all the subsequent elements.  However, most programming languages don't provide a concept like "circular arrays".

If instead of arrays, a linked list is being used, then the link in the element prior to the one being dequeued can be changed to point to the subsequent element (after the one being dequeued).  This will work both for a linear linked list and a circular linked list.